# Django queryset returns nothing for character 'i' in CharField

Tags: django, sqlite, django-queryset, django-2.0

I'm trying to write  search view to find records by filtering with icontains in a CharField in sqlite table. But some records starts with 'İ' and queryset returns nothing when user submits search form with typing **'i'** instead of **'İ'**.

If record starts with 'i' view runs correctly.

Also I ran SQL query for the same table with using LIKE but query returned nothing.

Django 2.0
Sqlite 3

**Edit 1:** icontains is case-insensitive but it tests for 'I' if word has 'i' char, but I need it to test for 'İ'. Also it doesn't test if you type 'ı' for 'I'.

I changed my view and add this code for 'i' - 'İ' and it works. But there must be another solution for this problem instead of this workaround.

```
if query.startswith('i'):
        text = query[:0] + 'İ' + query[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may convert the accented character to ASCII by unidecode()

```
import unidecode
accented_string = 'İ'
unaccented_string = unidecode.unidecode(accented_string)
YourClass.objects.get(text__icontains=unaccented_string)
```

Comment: There is no problem with words starting with 'İ'.  If user types 'i' instead of 'İ', filter with icontains returns nothing. Example: word is 'İnc' uıser types 'inc' and there is no search result.